# Image popup, without postback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, imaging

I am making my own photo album, and want to copy the functionality of a well known photo sharing site. What I am looking for is - how do they do this?

http://www.flickr.com/photos/cdotlister/6445556533/in/photostream/

That's a photo of mine. If you click the photo, you get an enlarged version. The initial one and the large one are the same file size, so, must be the same file. I think the smaller one is resized using html. (image height and width). And then the popup version is probably the actaul image size.

However, when the image is popped up - resize your window. It stays centred.

I'd like to replicate this... I assume it'd ajax? I'd like to know how I can have a click event on the image, display a popped up version of the same image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at jQuery lightbox pluggin.

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/